# Get the OS/Platform in Nancy

Tags: nancy

Is there an equivalent of the 'Platform' in Nancyfx?

In as asp.net I can do the following:
Request.Browser.Platform

Answer (score 5):

Nothing out of the box right now, but you have access to the headers so you could parse it out of it yourself.

You should parse the *User-Agent HTTP header* that you can read from Request.Headers["User-Agent"] .. you could add an extension method for it, or on *Request*

If you create something reusable then please consider contirbuting it back to the framework

Thanks!

Comment: seems there's no documentation about Request & Response